# How to host java application in AWS EC2 linuix machine?

Tags: java, jsp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I developed a java web application using Eclipse (JSP,Servlet), as back end I am using MYSQL, for hosting this application I created Linux machine in EC2 instance.
On the EC2 machine I installed TOMCAT7 and MYSQL (database), I deployed my application in Tomcat.

**Directory structure in Tomcat7**
[image: directory structure in Tomcat7]

JDBC jar file I put inside WEB-INF/lib. When I am accessing my application remotely then I am able to access JSP page that is my login page, in login page in putting Login ID and Password after my request transferred into servlet page in which I am taking login ID and password.

After that I am calling Database method to check UserID and Password ; if password and Login ID are correct then I am transferring request into some page but after that my servlet is not able to call Database method and it's showing following output:

**Output:**
[image: output]

Comment: If the content is empty then  transferring request into some page is failed, and you need to check your code.

Comment: hi thanks for reply..but My code working in eclipse properly..!!!!

Comment: Are there any errors in Tomcat/logs/catalina.yyyy-mm-dd file?

Comment: For webapps, you should look into Elastic bean stalk !

Comment: yes there are 4 files catalina.yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: @LouisF. Elastic bean stalk?

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html

Comment: @Dukefirehawk yes error is as following.....ERROR MESSAGE//an 16, 2016 2:30:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib

Comment: That won't cause your problem. I'd suggest checking 1.  MySQL connection from the command line using mysql. 2, Tomcat directory ownership and permissions especially Tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost. The user that runs Tomcat must have read/write permission to this folder.